# The characterization of an interval theorem.

Tags: real-analysis

Here's the 1.5 pages where my text defines intervals. I'm having a difficult time understanding the characterization theorem.

[image]

[image]

If we just consider the first case in the theorem that $S$ is bounded. We are given that $S$ contains at least two points. But what if it contains *only* two points? Then there's no possible way $S$ could be an interval. But the proof opens up with "Let $a = \inf S$ and let $ b = \sup S$. If $a < z$ then $z$ is not a lower bound of $S$... etc. "

So this characterization theorem is basically saying that, for example, the set $S := \{3,5\}$ is an interval? That seems like a definition of sorts not a theorem.

This is how the proof seems to me:

Consider the set $S := \{3,5\}$. $\inf S = 3$ and $\sup S = 5$. Now $3<4$ so $4$ is not a lower bound of $S$. Therefore there exists an element of $S$ in between $3$ and $4$.

Comment: Please cut out unimportant things like the adidas logo!

Comment: @Fakemistake lol

Comment: Just seems like too much work to crop for every picture post. I think as long as there's no identifying or offensive information then it's fine.

Comment: If $3,5$ belong to $S$ then the entire interval $[3,5]$ must be a subset of $S$. This fails with $S=\{3,5\}$.

Comment: But $S = \{3,5\}$ meets the criteria of the theorem doesn't it. $3,5 \in S$, $3<5$ ... I don't understand the next "then" statement. I thought "then" was taken to mean "implies" in mathematics?

Comment: @Zduff nope: the criteria of theorem is that if $x,y \in S$ with $x<y$ then $t \in S$ for all $x\le t\le y$. This is false in your example..

Comment: But what if $S = \{3\} \cup [3.5, 4.5] \cup \{5\}$, $S$ is *not* an interval, am I right? But there is an $x,y \in S$ such that all $t \in [x,y]$.

Answer (score 0):

No, the theorem do not say that {3,4} is an interval.
S={3,4} does not verify the assumption of the theorem : 
$x=3 \in S$ and $y=4 \in S$, but [x,y]=[3,4] is not included in S.

Remark: Another way to state the charaterization Theorem is to say that the convex subsets of $\mathbb R$ are its convex sets.

Comment: The assumption of the theorem as a "then" in it, as in: if $x,y\in S$ and $x<y$, *then* $[x,y]$ is a subset of $S$. So doesn't that part imply that there's an interval automatically in $S$?

Comment: I think you mean "the convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are its intervals".

Comment: No, I don't know what "convex" means in the context you're using it.

Comment: My comment was referred to olivier pantz. However, a subset $C$ of a (real) vector space is said to be convex iff for all $x,y \in C$ and all $t \in [0,1]$ it holds $tx+(1+t)y \in C$.

Comment: OK Zduff... I can now see where your mistake is... the assumption of the Theorem is "if $x,y \in S$ and $x<y$ then $[x,y]\subset S$".  The conclusion is "S is an interval". The theorem does NOT state that for all $S$, "if $x,y \in S$ and $x<y$ then $[x,y] \subset S$".

Answer (score 0):

No, $S=\{3,5\}$ is not an interval, indeed it does not satisfy the above property (see Paramanand Singh's comment).

The preliminary observation is: Every interval $S\subseteq \mathbf{R}$ with $|S|\ge 2$ is convex.

The characterization theorem states the converse: Let $S\subseteq \mathbf{R}$ be an *arbitrary* subset with $|S|\ge 2$ such that $S$ is convex. *Then* $S$ is an interval.